# Creating a form and displaying some of the data on another tab

Tags: forms

I am looking for options on how to create a form in Wordpress and then pull some of the data (but not all) that is collected onto another page. Example. The form would collect personal data and also answer some questions on recommendations. I would like to figure out the best way to pull the recommendations only on to a recommendations page.

Comment: If you're already collecting the data I assume you're putting it into the DB, so after form submission, just retrieve the data from the DB.  Or se the submission to redirect to the recommendations page and attach some query parameters to the end of the URL. This is a really open ended question.  To get results on WPSE you should really try something and then post a code sample if you need help getting it to work.  A dozen people here could each give you multiple different 'suggestions' but none of us can know if they'll actually work or if you'll be able to implement them.